# Where has my user installed my web setup project?

Tags: windows-installer, virtual-directory, web-setup-project

I have a web setup project, and a web service project in visual studio 08

In my web setup project i allow the user to choose his virtual directory name and by the end of the installation i have an installer class in my web service project that "wants" to do some stuff such as opening a web page with the web service home page installed.

The thing is that i know how to pass parameters from the web setup project such as TARGETDIR in my installer class but i can't figure out the URL of what he installed. IE if he installed a virtual directory named foo i can assume that he it is located at http://localhost/foo but what if i miss some configuration of the IIS and maybe the website is located under http://localhost/whatever/foo ?

So, to keep it relatively short, by the end of the installation i need to know in my installer class my web service's URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installer variable for the Virtual Directory is `TARGETVDIR`.